# jboss not picking the war in deployment folder

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, jboss7.x, war

**JBoss Version**: jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

I have copied my '**war**' to deployment folder : /usr/share/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments

when I start the JBoss, It is **not deploying the war**, It is starting and stuck with the following logs,

```
/usr/share/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/standalone.sh -c standalone.xml -b testname.com
=========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /usr/share/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

  JAVA: java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+TieredCompilation -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml

=========================================================================

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
16:52:50,529 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.5.GA
16:52:51,130 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
16:52:51,186 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Harry

Comment: Create a `<warName>.dodeploy` file in the same directory and see if it picks it up automatically or if it doesn’t, try a restart.

Comment: What version of java is used to run the JBoss AS. Try with any other java version

Comment: @achAmháin Is this correct

total 20
-rw-r--r-- 1 jboss jboss 8870 Mar 10  2012 README.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jboss jboss 4709 Dec 21 18:03 kerberoes-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jboss jboss    0 Dec 21 18:04 kerberoes-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war.dodeploy

Still it is not picking up, I tried restarting too

Comment: @Harry it's hard to tell what your error is. The fact that your logging ends on *JBoss...starting* and doesn't go further is strange. Could be an issue with the `standalone.xml`. Can you log on to the admin console? If so, try the deployment from there.

Answer (score 1):

JBoss AS 7.1.x is not compatible with JDK 8. If you want to JDK 8 then you should upgrade to WildFly or use JDK 7.